# ModernCV change entrance indent to fit date in one line

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I am writing my CV using the `moderncv` LaTeX template. Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}     
\moderncvstyle{casual}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{X}{Y}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}% \footnotemark}
\cventry{09.2014-00.2099 }{Master of Science}{University}{City}{\textit{Stuff}}{More stuff.}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be

\end{document}
```

If you run this code, you can see that below the blue, thick line, the date of the `cventry` is reported.

What I do not like is that the date is reported on two rows. More than one person told me it is not clearly readable.

Therefore my question is: how can I change it in order to make the date stay on one row without changing the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, class `moderncv` has a special layout, at last for the content you have two columns.

Let's say the first column (for the date or range of date) is called "hints", then I think the command `\hintscolumnwidth` is obvious: it contains the width of the first columns of the table for contents.

The command `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}` makes the first column 3cm.  Play with this number for your needs.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}     
\moderncvstyle{casual}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{X}{Y}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % <==================================


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}% \footnotemark}
\cventry{09.2014-00.2099 }{Master of Science}{University}{City}{\textit{Stuff}}{More stuff.}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be

\end{document}
```

which gives the result:

[image]

instead of the result of your code:

[image]